# error ESLint Airbnb state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Tengo el siguiente componente de clase en React el cual uso `ESLint` para revisión de codigo usando las reglas de `Airbnb` pero al momento de declarar mi `state = { ... }` el linter me indica que existe un error en el `=` con el mensaje:

> Parsing error: Unexpected token = eslint [4,9]

Mi codigo:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Index extends Component {
  state = {
    state: true
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div />
    );
  }
}
```

¿Quien sabe a que se debe este error en el linter? aplique la configuración por defecto de airbnb.

package.json

```
{
    "devDependencies": {
        "eslint": "^6.2.2",
        "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.0.1",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.18.2",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.14.3",
        "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^1.7.0"
    }
}
```

.eslintrc.json

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es6": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "airbnb"
    ],
    "globals": {
        "Atomics": "readonly",
        "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
    },
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        },
        "ecmaVersion": 2018,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react"
    ],
    "rules": {}
}
```

Comment: No será porque has envuelto la propiedad state entre `''`?

Comment: No, eso fue error mio de tipeo. Sin las comillas en el state da el mismo error en el linter.